# Command injection bypass filter

Tags: php

i was trying bypass all day this code, this code is from DVWA hight security,i tried characters, encoders, etc, but i didnt have a good answer
 somebody knows that is possible to bypass:

```
if( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) ) {

$target = $_REQUEST["ip"];

$target = stripslashes( $target );


// Split the IP into 4 octects
$octet = explode(".", $target);

// Check IF each octet is an integer
if ((is_numeric($octet[0])) && (is_numeric($octet[1])) && (is_numeric($octet[2])) && (is_numeric($octet[3])) && (sizeof($octet) == 4)  ) {

// If all 4 octets are int's put the IP back together.
$target = $octet[0].'.'.$octet[1].'.'.$octet[2].'.'.$octet[3];


    // Determine OS and execute the ping command.
    if (stristr(php_uname('s'), 'Windows NT')) { 

        $cmd = shell_exec( 'ping  ' . $target );
        echo '<pre>'.$cmd.'</pre>';

    } else { 

        $cmd = shell_exec( 'ping  -c 3 ' . $target );
        echo '<pre>'.$cmd.'</pre>';

    }

}

else {
    echo '<pre>ERROR: You have entered an invalid IP</pre>';
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how old your DVWA is. In 2015, the one labeled "High" is now "Impossible".

https://github.com/ethicalhack3r/DVWA/blob/87c987e2804a7fb11507a4c6b66dc49958572fe5/vulnerabilities/exec/source/impossible.php

With what you have written, there is not any way that I've ever heard of to bypass it.